# invalid use of incomplete type / forward declaration of errors. possible missuse of abstract class? (C++)

Tags: c++, abstract, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

now i get the error:

```
error: ‘oset<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >   >::Comparator’ is an inaccessible base of ‘CaseSensitive’
```

I've been trying to figure out the issue for several hours to no avail, hopefully one of you guys can help me. relevant code is below:

```
template <class T>
class oset;

template <class T>
class oset {

....

 public:
    class Comparator {
 public:
    virtual ~Comparator() {}
    virtual int compare(T, T) = 0;
};

 private:
    Comparator *comp;

....

 public:
    // new empty set:
    oset(Comparator*);
....

};

....

class CaseSensitive : oset<string>::Comparator
{
    public:
        virtual ~CaseSensitive(){}
        virtual int compare(string str1, string str2)
        {
            return strcmp(str1.c_str(), str2.c_str());
        }
};
....

int main() {
    oset<string>::Comparator *cs = new class CaseSensative();
    //error in line above

    ....

}
```

What I am trying to do is make an abstract Comparator object so that I can define custom typological orders to sort oset with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting privately from `Comparator`, so that the inheritance relationship is not available outside members and friends of the class. In particular, that prevents conversion from `CaseSensitive*` to `Comparator*`. You probably want to inherit publicly:

```
class CaseSensitive : public oset<string>::Comparator // added "public"
{
    // members here
};
```

Unless you specify otherwise, members and base classes of a `class` are `private`; and those of a `struct` are `public`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `new CaseSensative()` (which is spelled 'sensitive', BTW), and the full definition of that class must be available (you most likely didn't include a header which defines it).

Well, or you defined one class and try to use non-existing one, in which case it should be `new IgnoreCase()`.

Comment: oh woops i ment for that to be the case sensitive version, not ignore case, let me fix that

Comment: so I added the casesensitive code. it also turns out that I had a type in main, which you pointed out. I fixed that type and got a new error. I changed the info i give to address this.

Answer (score 0):

You should include CaseSensative in your question. Unless that's the problem.

Comment: so I fixed that mistake in my question, I also had a type, now my error is as follows:  error: ‘oset<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Comparator’ is an inaccessible base of ‘CaseSensitive’

Comment: @GarrettRosenblatt: You will need to inherit **public** -ally to be able to use a pointer-to-base. - When you inherit privately (default for classes), it means this inheritance relation is but an implementation detail that the rest of the world cannot know about.